# How to achieve custom appbar layout scrollable effect in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliverappbar

I tried to use Flutter `SliverAppBar` within `CustomScrollView` but that doesn't work as I want.

[image]

Comment: please add what you tried.

Comment: Did you want the app bar to shrink and then be scrolled up, or always stay visible after being shrunk?

Comment: @avinash I am trying to achieve something similar like your image showing, did you able to make it work? How did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `SliverAppBar` and have an app bar that shrinks and sticks to the top you can follow this example:

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 200.0,
        floating: true,
        snap: true,
        pinned: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text('SliverAppBar 1'),
          centerTitle: true,
          background: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('text 1'),
              Text('text 2'),
              Text('text 3'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (context, index) {
            return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              child: Text('SliverList item'),
              height: 60,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            );
          },
          childCount: 20
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

Comment: Great ! but it's not translating circular image

Comment: I know that was in your screenshot, but your question was about the scrollable effect and keeping the appbar visible. Having an inner widget move horizontally at the same time as the appbar hides is possible, but it is an different question that requires a more extensive solution. I would advise you to mark an answer as correct if it fixed your question, and open a new question specific to the translating of a widget based on the movement of SliverAppBar.

Comment: Anyway, i'm happy with this solution also.

Comment: I've seen a colleague with solution similar to what you want to do. So I know it's possible. Open a new question specific to that, and if not me, I'm sure someone will have the answer. I'm glad I could help.